# Limit to ElseIf Conditions?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

So I have some VBA code designed to go through a few things based on a value in a cell. The value in the cell is read and the code runs accordingly. This works without issue with.

```
If Target.Value = "something" Then
End If
ElseIf Target.Value = "something2" Then
End If
ElseIf Target.Value = "something3" Then
End If
ElseIf Target.Value = "something4" Then
End If
```

That works perfectly, however if I add an additional ElseIf condition I get the compiler error of "Else without If". Changing ElseIf to Else on the fifth condition doesn't fix the issue. My question is that is there a limit to the amount of ElseIf conditions I can run? I literally only need this fifth one to be entirely done with what I am trying to do. I am positive the code within the condition has no errors.

Comment: *"This works without issue"* What? sure????

Comment: Ahhhh that's what it is... The code's a bit messy so I assumed the EndIf of the last ElseIf statement was in all the others but it's not. My mistake shoulda caught that one.

Comment: *is there a limit to the amount of ElseIf conditions I can run* - nope (module will stop compiling after 10K lines though). The limit is *how many can you mentally keep track of*. At one point you should consider a `Select Case` block instead, and if possible at another point you would consider having a separate procedure per case, and perhaps a `CallByName` or `Application.Run` call that runs the appropriate method - then you could have a `Dictionary` keyed with `Target.Value` values and valued with procedure names, and just go `Application.Run strategies(Target.Value)`, makes it a 1-liner!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The End If goes at the end only:

```
If Target.Value = "something" Then
    'Do something
ElseIf Target.Value = "something2" Then
    'Do something
ElseIf Target.Value = "something3" Then
    'Do something
ElseIf Target.Value = "something4" Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Comment: Yeah I see my mistake now haha. Still new to this thank you for the response!

Answer (score 9):

Definitely you should "upgrade" your multiple `ElseIf` and go with `Select Case`.

This will let you implement more scenarios in the future easier.

```
Select Case Target.Value
    Case "something"
        ' code 1 here

    Case "something2"
        ' code 2 here

    Case "something3"
        ' code 3 here

    Case "something4"
        ' code 4 here

    Case "something5", "something6" ' <-- replaces using another If with And
        ' code 5 here

    ' Case ....

End Select
```

Comment: Okay I'll give it a look! Thank you for the response!

Comment: @GingerbreadPK once you'll try `Select Case` you'll never go back :)